# Regular expression does not fit to pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I want to go through a list of header files, and save the files which those include. My problem is that the pattern does not match.

In this link you can find the pattern which I thought will work: https://regex101.com/r/jbJLxT/3

```
string rgxPat = "\\#include\\s+\"(?:\\w+\\/)*(\\w +\\.(?:hed|he|hdb|h))\"";
Regex incLRgx = new Regex(rgxPat, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
for (int i = alrdyChckd; i < missFiles.Count; i++)
{
    tmpStr = baseSBFolder + "\\" + missFiles[i].getPath() + "\\" + missFiles[i].getName();
    System.IO.StreamReader actFile = new System.IO.StreamReader(tmpStr);
    while((actLine = actFile.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        Match match = incLRgx.Match(actLine);
        if(match.Success)
        {
    missFiles.Add(baseSB.getFileByName(match.Groups[1].Value.ToString()));
        }
    }
    alrdyChckd++;
}
```

I checked the debug varaibles and the match function always give back false return value, while the pattern and the actual line seems to be the same. 
Also it's a problem that I cannot add double qoutes as I wanted with the string = @"[pettern]" form because the double queste will close the pattern.

Comment: Are you trying to get the entire path or the basename only?

Comment: Look into `using`/`IDisposable` for your `StreamReader` and also `Path.Combine()` instead of all that string concatenation with hard-coded `\\`.

Comment: The only issue is a typo: you inserted a space between `\w` and `+`. Replace ``\\/`` with `/` in the C# code. `match.Groups[1].Value.ToString()` = `match.Groups[1].Value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you the paths:

```
/^\#include\s+"(.+)"$/gm
```

Output of `$1`:

```
FSW/CustSW/CustSW_generic/RSC/Src/gen/rsc_cpif.h
EbsPartition/EbsCluster/EbsCluster_generic/EbsCore/Src/ebscore_basetypes.h
FSW/CustSW/CustSW_generic/RSC/Src/gen/rsc_types.h
```

---

If you want just the filenames then use:

```
/^\#include\s+".*\/([^\/]+)"$/gm
```

and `$1` will give you:

```
rsc_cpif.h
ebscore_basetypes.h
rsc_types.h
```

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the group by name to get the file path:

```
\#include(?<path>\s+"(?:\w+\/)*(\w+\.(?:hed|he|hdb|h))")

match.Groups["path"].Value.ToString()
```

This will give you the file path captured as `"FSW/CustSW/CustSW_generic/RSC/Src/gen/rsc_cpif.h"`